# Objective C Error: C style method inside Class implementation?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, function

I created a class and have some outside methods in a `Functions.h` header (think thats the problem). Anyway, when ever I try to use any type of C-style function in the class implementation file; even blank ones, I get a compiler/ liker error. I am new to this and don't understand what the problem is.  I'm thinking I can't use the `.h` file, but I am able to use global vars and directives in the class file.

Where am I suppose to declare my outside functions? In what kind of file?

Comment: can you show us a bit of your code? That way we can perhaps give a more targeted answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is causing the error, and the exact error message you're receiving.

Comment: Ill load it in later, but its c style functions examples  

void punchSound()
{
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sIDPunch);
}

im trying to put it here
in the view controller implementation class
-(IBAction) punch
{
    //punchSound();
}

the c style function is in a .h file wasnt sure how it was suppose to be set up :(

Comment: @Thankmelater23: And what do the error messages say? My answer guesses that they complain about multiple definitions; if that's not the case, please let us know so I can change the answer.

Comment: This is the code I get after un-commenting the c style function in the code

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you fully define the functions (including implementation) in a header file, and include that from multiple source files; and that the errors you forgot to describe say something about "multiple definitions" or "duplicate symbols":

```
// Header file
void some_function() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

If that is the case, you need to *either* move the definitions into a source file, leaving just declarations in the header, so they only have a single definition:

```
// Header file
void some_function();

// Source file
void some_function() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

*or* declare the definitions `inline`, which allows them to be included in more than one source file:

```
// Header file
inline void some_function() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

If that isn't the problem, please post some example code and error messages so we don't have to guess what's happening.

Comment: Thanks mike ill get on it now.  What source file extension should I use?  I'll play with it, but should I use .mm or .m or what?  And as far as directives is there anything special that should or should not be in there. Here is my header file

Comment: @Thankmelater23: If it's Objective-C++, then `.mm` is the conventional source file extension; plain C++ is usually `.cpp`, though you might also see `.cxx`, `.cc` or even `.C`. I don't know enough about Objective languages to answer the other question.

Answer (score 2):

You have `c++` as a tag. Perhaps these functions are C++ functions but you're trying to get at them from an Obj-C file? If that's the case, you either need to turn them into C functions, or you need to use Obj-C++ (which has the `.mm` extension instead of `.m`).

Comment: duplicate symbol _punchSound in:
    /Users/helloagain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fight_1.0-evogqjuhjykmcwafbkdtamyziszv/Build/Intermediates/Fight 1.0.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fight 1.0.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o
    /Users/helloagain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fight_1.0-evogqjuhjykmcwafbkdtamyziszv/Build/Intermediates/Fight 1.0.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fight 1.0.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Player.o
ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @Thankmelater23: You've defined the function twice. Did you perhaps put the definition in the header, without marking it inline?

Comment: Yes I created a prototype then defined it in the same file, but I didnt inline it though. Is that the issue?

Comment: @Thankmelater23: Yes. Every time your header is included, you're now creating a separate definition for the function. This violates the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: @Thankmelater23: Typically you only declare the method in the header, and you define it in the corresponding source file. Unless you really do want it to be inline, then you just mark it as `inline`.

Comment: So where would I store the defined c style methods?  I come from a C++ background

Comment: @Thankmelater23: Then you should already know the answer. This isn't an Obj-C problem, it's a C/C++ problem.

Comment: //
//  Functions.h
//  Fight 1.0
//
//  Created by Andre on 3/13/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 HnG Studios. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Globals:Constants.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@class Player;//Might casue a problem


#ifndef Fight_1_0_Functions_h
#define Fight_1_0_Functions_h
//functions 
#endif

should i change anything differently in my source file?

Comment: Is there someone I could forward my project to that can point out the issue I still can't figure it out and I honestly don't really know how to use this site. I'm learning though!